# <input> font size keeps changing its width

Tags: html, css

So basically I have this

```css
#calculator {
  background-color: #212121;
  border-radius: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
}

#functionality {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 15px 5px 5px 15px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#display_calc {
  max-width: 91%;
  width: 91%;
  height: 70px;
  background-color: #1a1a1a;
}

#display {
  min-width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 50px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 50, 0, 5);
  color: white;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="calculator">
  <div id="functionality">
    <div id="display_calc">
      <input id="display">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

When I change the font size from display, the width gets very wide. I tried many things but nothing helps.

I tried putting many restrictions to the divs but the max width of the input does not work.

Comment: Can you clarify what you're doing here - `change the font size from display`?

Comment: @fubar I imagine OP doesn't want the width of their component to change when they change the input font size.

Comment: The issue seems centred around `inline-block`. Not sure why you want to use that or what the solution might be but without that display property, your widths are fixed

Comment: @Phil, it seems to me the property "display" is causing this, apart from "display: none", everyone of the declaration inside the property is causing the same problem

Comment: Seems like it's working as designed. I run it, and the `input` never gets wider than its containing element (100%). Is there something you are doing to make that happen?

Comment: @HereticMonkey I used the dev tools to change the font size and the entire component changes size

Comment: I want to use `inline-block` because I wantt `calculator` to fix size according another inner divs, not only the `display` div

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to fit the input to screen width, removing `display: inline-block;` from `#calculator` worked fine.
But If you wanna keep display inline you can add `width: 100%;` to `#calculator`

Answer (score 0):

The combination of inline-block and percentage width is what create the issue. You need to define a width (or max-width on the inline-block element) and remove some other styles

```css
#calculator {
  background-color: #212121;
  border-radius: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%; /* or max-width: 100%; */
}

#functionality {
  margin: 15px 5px 5px 15px;
}

#display_calc {
  height: 70px;
  background-color: #1a1a1a;
}

#display {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 50px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 50, 0, 5);
  color: white;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="calculator">
  <div id="functionality">
    <div id="display_calc">
      <input id="display">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```